# Floating point exception in C

Tags: c, exception, floating-point

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

long fctl(int n){
  int a=1,i;
  for(i=n;i>1;--i)
    a*=i;
  return a;
}

long ch(int n, int r){
  return fctl(n) / (fctl(n-r)*fctl(r));
}

int main(){
  char *hands[] = {"onepair", "twopair", "triple", "straight", "flush", "fullhouse", "fourofakind", "straightflush", "royalflush"};
  double handprobs[9];

  handprobs[0] = ch(13,1)*ch(4,2) * ch(12,3)*pow(ch(4,1), 3) / ch(52,5);
  handprobs[1] = ch(13,2)*pow(ch(4,2), 2) * ch(11,1)*ch(4,1) / ch(52,5);
  handprobs[2] = ch(13,1)*ch(4,3) * ch(12,2)*pow(ch(4,1), 2) / ch(52,5);
  handprobs[3] = 10.0 * pow(ch(4, 1),5) / ch(52, 5)  -  10.0/ch(52,5) - 4.0/ch(52,5);
  handprobs[4] = ch(13,5)*ch(4,1) / ch(52, 5) - 10.0/ch(52,5);
  handprobs[5] = ch(13,1)*ch(4,3) * ch(12,1)*ch(4,2) / ch(52,5);
  handprobs[6] = ch(13,1)*1 * ch(12,1)*ch(4,1) / ch(52,5);
  handprobs[7] = 40.0 / ch(52, 5) - 4.0/ch(52,5),
  handprobs[8] = 4.0 / ch(52, 5);
  int i;
  for(i=0;hands[i];++i){
    printf("%s\t%f\n",hands[i], handprobs[i]);
  }
}
```

When I compile it returns "Floating point exception (core dumped)", not sure why. (Have tried converting all the probs with (double).) Any ideas?

Comment: Most likely a divide by zero - just run your code under a debugger to identify the exact problem.

Comment: for(i=0;hands[i];++i) ?!

Comment: Good luck computing 52!.

Comment: Statements for `handprobs[7]` and `[8]` assignments are separated with a comma operator instead of a semicolon for no apparent reason. It is generally more sensible to use a semicolon, though it won't make much difference in this case.

Comment: By the way, you *can* compute many binomial coefficients (all those appearing in your code) in native C types, but you have to be a little clever about it and avoid computing lots of unnecessary values.

Comment: @Calvin1602 yeah, as in, while hands[i] exists...

Comment: you can hardcode your `ch(52,5)` as 2598960, `ch(13,1)` as 13, `ch(13,2)` as 78 and `ch(13,5)` as 1287. The others should be no problem.

Comment: hands+9 does point somewhere in memory, but I wouldn't bet that the compiler sets it to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fctl(52)` is waaaaay too big for an `int`. You're going to have to rethink your approach to doing this calculation.  You can output `INT_MAX` to see how far you can actually go. You can buy a tiny bit more space by using `unsigned long long` (cf. `ULLONG_MAX`) but that is still nowhere near big enough for `52!` .

Invoking integer overflow causes undefined behaviour; "floating point exception" often means attempt to do integer division by zero, which is plausible given your attempted calculations plus the fact that they overflowed. Don't ask me why this is reported as FPE despite the fact that it didn't involve any floating point. (probably "historical reasons")

Comment: @Kay: it is actually sufficient to have 225bit int.

Comment: Goddamnit. Yeah thanks for pointing that out, should have thought about it more.

Comment: possibly at some point the low bits of fctl is all 0 and result in a div-by-0

Answer (score 1):

After accept answer.

@Matt McNabb wells points out that `fctl(52)` is certianly to big for a vaid numeric result to fit in an `long`.  (@mrVoid asserts 225 bit `int` needed.)

But certain @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc is on the right track as to what caused the exception.

`fctl(x)` will be the product of numbers `1` to `x`, half of those are even.  Thus `fctl(x)` will have `x/2` LSbits set to zero.

Assuming 32-bit `int`, once the number of LSBits of `fctl(n-r)` and `fctl(r)` exceed/meet 32, the product `(fctl(n-r)*fctl(r))` will be 0 and `return fctl(n) / (0);` throws an exception.

On many systems an integer divide by 0 is reported as an floating-point error.  I *think* this oddity occurs to simplify trap handling.